# Fish shell slow to respond when command does not exist

Tags: fish

When I write a command that does not exist in the `fish` shell (let's say `l` instead of `ls`), fish takes some time before responding that the command does not exist.

I don't know if it looks for package to install or something else, but it is a bit annoying and I need to hit `Ctrl-C` to avoid waiting a few seconds.

Is there a way to disable this "feature", whatever it is?

Comment: This is probably the command-not-found handler. What is your operating system?

Comment: GNU/Linux (ArchLinux). I found out that if I enter twice the same wrong command, the second time I wait less time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the other answer does not work anymore, I found [another solution](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/pull/2331) which consists of adding this function in `config.fish`:

```
function __fish_command_not_found_handler --on-event fish_command_not_found
    echo "fish: Unknown command '$argv'"
end
```

Answer (score 5):

As ridiculous_fish says, this is probably due to the command-not-found handler.

You can try adding [this suggestion](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/2231) to your `config.fish`:

```
function __fish_default_command_not_found_handler --on-event fish_command_not_found
  functions --erase __fish_command_not_found_setup
  echo "'$argv' not found"
end
```

Comment: Thanks. With this function, I get the message twice, but I does not solve the issue (it is as slow as before). At first, I thought that it could take some time to look in `$PATH`, but the syntax highlighting is quick, so I am not sure it could causes this issue. What else could cause this issue?

Comment: You could run fish under `strace` and see what it's blocking on.

Comment: One noticeable difference when running `strace` is that I see more `select(8, [7], NULL, NULL, {0, 10000})  = 0 (Timeout)` when it is slower. What does it mean?

Comment: Could you open an issue on Github and we can try to get to the bottom of it?

Comment: That was indeed the solution. For some reason, `fish` did not load it correctly the first time I tried this solution. After a reboot, everything is fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is a streamlined, documented and hopefully long-term supported way to override this by declaring custom `fish_command_not_found` function.

`~/.config/fish/functions/fish_command_not_found.fish`:

```bsh
function fish_command_not_found
    echo "fish: Unknown command '$argv'" >&2
end
```

http://fishshell.com/docs/current/cmds/fish_command_not_found.html

Comment: How is this different from the accepted answer?

Comment: @DaniyalAhmadSE, See the linked doc. Using `--on-event fish_command_not_found` is a legacy approach, and should be replaced with a function with given name going forward.